# Python Socket - last symbol is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

So, I created client and server sing socket.
And everything works well, but i just broke then using string from MySQL database.

Server:

```
import socket
import threading


PORT = 9696
SERVER = "localhost"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)


def handle_client(conn):
    while True:
        actual_size = int(conn.recv(30).decode(FORMAT).replace("#", ""))
        size = int(actual_size / 1024)
        rest_msg = actual_size - (size * 1024)
        received_message = ""
        for chunk in range(size):
            received_message += conn.recv(1024).decode(FORMAT)
        received_message += conn.recv(rest_msg).decode(FORMAT)
        print(rest_msg)
        print(len(received_message))


def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn,))
        thread.start()


start()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import time

HEADER = 64
PORT = 9696
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
SERVER = "localhost"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)


def send(msg):
    client.send(msg.encode("utf-8"))


msg_to_send = "Some random message"

time.sleep(3)
for i in range(1000):
    send(str(len(msg_to_send)) + ("#" * (30 - len(str(len(msg_to_send)))) + msg_to_send))

while True:
    pass
```

If I replace `msg_to_send` with following text:

```
[('index', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', 'MUL', None, ''), ('LP', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), (' NR-a', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('LITERA-a', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('MUFA-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('UWAGI-a', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('TUBY-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DATA1-a', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DATA2-a', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('SPAWY-i', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('SPAWY_DAC-i', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('LOG-a', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('SPLIT1X4-i', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('SPLIT1X8-i', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('SPLIT1X16-i', 'text', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('ADAPTERY SIMPLE-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('ADAPTERY DUPLEX-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('PIGTAIL-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('OLT-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('NEXT-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('ODNOGA_1-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('ODNOGA_2-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('ODNOGA_3-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('ODNOGA_4-a', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP30-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP50-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP70-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP80-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP100-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP120-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP150-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('DROP200-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, ''), ('MAŁPKI-i', 'double', 'YES', '', None, '')]
```

And it lost `]`, so the next message if it will be converted to int so it can read how long next message will be it will just trow an error that for example `]6` is str.
I have complily no idea why this is happening. I arledy tried with diffrent table from databse and changed buffer size but it still eating somewhere this one peace.
And there are two prints in server. First show buffer that were used while receiving that. And second one for showing how many symbols it actually received and it always works but not with that string.

If I didn't cover something here or some important info, please write in comment and I will provide it.

Comment: `conn.recv()` can return less than you ask for, unless you use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag.

Comment: Although @Barmar is correct, that's not the cause of your problem.  The problem is that your production string contains a non-ASCII character.  Thus, although the string in Unicode is 1481 characters, and that's what you embed, when it gets converted to UTF-8 for transmission, the resulting string is 1482 bytes long.  You need to convert to UTF-8 BEFORE you compute the length.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the correction. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your production string contains a non-ASCII character, and that gets converted to multiple bytes when you encode to UTF-8.  Those multiple bytes are not accounted for in your length transmission.  You need to grab the length AFTER converting.  So, get rid of the "send" function and do:

```
msg_to_send = msg_to_send.encode('utf-8')
for i in range(1000):
    print(len(msg_to_send))
    prefix = (str(len(msg_to_send)) + "#"*30)[:30].encode('utf-8')
    client.send(prefix + msg_to_send)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: That, works! Thanks you, but what does `[:30]` make?

Comment: That says "take the first 30 characters of".  Rather than go to the trouble of computing how many # to add, I just add 30 and cut off the resulting string at 30.